# Manipulate the 3rd party library UI css style without unlocking the encapsulation or using ng-deep in Angular

Tags: angular

I want to manipulate the 3rd party library css used in a component and apparently, the style I plan on applying needs to be either in `style.css`(global css), or in the component style file along with setting the `encapsulation` as `ViewEncapsulation.None`. But the problem is they will become global style and could cause the potential collision. I've digged for a couple of articles and they recommend `ng-deep` approach but it's noted "deprecated" so I don't want to go for it.

Is there any other workaround?

Comment: `::ng-deep` noted as deprecated but they won't remove it until there is an alternative option

Comment: @David I know it's been stated deprecated forever. I just wonder if there's any other workaround